# Is it possiple to discharge the positive charge only from a capacitor and maintain the negative charge?

Tags: capacitor

Is it possiple to discharge the positive charge only from a capacitor and maintain the negative charge ?

Comment: +1 because it's not so trivial. See my answer.

Comment: Explain? First thought would be a resistor-diode in parallel with the capacitor?

Comment: That would lower the voltage difference between plates and increase the common mode voltage. What purpose could that serve?

Answer (score 2):

No. A capacitor only has one charge. The charge creates a voltage differential to the capacitor. From the positive pin, the voltage is negative towards the other pin. From the negative pin, the voltage is positive towards the other pin. What you suggest would mean that there would need to be 3 pins and two capacitors.

It would help a little if you would tell us what you are trying to do, exactly. If you are trying to make a negative voltage, that can be done by switching to which nets the pins of the capacitor is connected to. Let's say you need to generate -5 volts from +5 volts. You can charge the capacitor between the +5V net and ground, then disconnect the capacitor, and then connect the + pin of the capacitor to the ground. The - pin of the capacitor now has -5 volts, when compared to ground.

As you discharge the capacitor, the voltage at the - pin will change towards the ground; from -5 volts to -4 volts, from -4 volts to -3 volts and so on. So you will need to switch the way the capacitor is connected again, and charge it from between the +5 volts and ground. This system is called a "charge pump".

Comment: You may not disconnect the capacitor just "connecting the + pin of the capacitor to the ground" (the ordinary CR differentiating circuit acts in this way). You have just to connect a diode in parallel to the capacitor (forward biased when +5 V is applied).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist, Umm... I have absolutely no idea what you just said. Although I might want to try to understand. What do you mean I "may not disconnect..", consider a simple experiment like: 1) take a 9V battery to your left hand 2) take a 10000 uF capacitor to your right hand. 3) connect the capacitor to the battery. 4) move the capacitor away from the battery. 5) connect positive terminal of capacitor to negative terminal of battery. 6) measure voltage of negative terminal of capacitor against the negative terminal of the battery. It will read -9 volts and drop down from there. What's CR?

Comment: You are right. This is the straightforward solution, and you have explained it in a very attractive way. But it needs two 3-terminal switches connected in something like an H bridge. I've just reminded that if we drive a CR differentiating circuit by positive pulses (switch only the left end of the capacitor), it will produce negative output pulses across the resistor (load).

Answer (score 0):

A common misconception is that the word charging or charged seems to imply that you're 'adding' or 'added' something to the capacitor. That's not the case. When you connect a battery or other source to a capacitor a charge current flows which moves charges from one plate to the other. When you discharge the capacitor the charges simply move back to the other plate either in full or partially.

The energy stored in the capacitor has increased but the net amount of charges for the capacitor as a whole remains the same, charged or uncharged.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: It depends.

Think of a charged parallel plate capacitor  (fig. 1) as known from physics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq5GYe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, place a third plate inside the capacitor and connect it to the right plate. (fig. 2).

The charge from the right plate will completely move to this new plate!

You can now disconnect the plates and move the third plate around (fig. 3). If the capacitor is not connected to anything, the left plate will maintain its initial charge, while the right maintains uncharged. So **yes**, it is possible.

Of course, this is a rather academic answer to your question.

<s>As usually you can not do this with capacitors as used in electronics, the answer is **no**, it's usually not possible.</s>

---

EDIT:

Thinking about it again, I come to the conclusion that theoretically it's possible:

Any insulated object forms a capacitor to it's environment. When connecting it to earth via a voltage source, charge will flow and the previously neutral object is charged.

If now you replace the generic object by a charged capacitor (left figure) and connect only one terminal, it would be possible to suck out the charge from this terminal, leaving the charge on the other unchanged:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4aq3y.png)</sup>

Now, a spherical object of 1cm diameter in a distance of 10cm to a ground plane forms a capacitance in the order of ~10pF:

If you replace the plane by a mirror charge, the capacitance of the two spheres is

$$C=2\pi\varepsilon_0 r\left(\ln 2 +0.57 - 0.5*\ln \left(\frac{d}{r}-2\right)+...\right)$$

with an additional factor of 2 because you need only half the voltage in the sphere - plane setup.

This gives at least a hint how much voltage you need to discharge your one side of the capacitor.

Yet, I have to say this is a academic / physical than an electrical engineering problem.

Comment: a charged capacitor not connected to any circuit , if we connect  + and _ pin together it will discharge instantly with a sound and flash . the qeustion . is there any method or a way to have the same result only using the + pin  (instantly) ? thanks and please excue me for any mistakes .

Comment: I edited my answer. You must either use an additional plate as in my first answer, or a voltage source as in my edit. As the first option will usually be difficult to realize, the second is the one that works.